# .Net Framework 4.5 Soap Request GZip header is not correct Error

Tags: header, gzip

I want to get some information from wsdl based web service. When I use .Net Framework 3.5 the code succesfully work and return data, but when I use .Net Framework 4.0 and above I get error message: **The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.**

My Code:

```
var pk = new bildirimPetrol8FirmaBultenPortTypeClient("xxHttpSoap11Endpoint");
var result1 = pk.getResult(71, new[] { TextBox1.Text });
```

Comment: Then it's probably not a gzip stream. Can you provide the first 30 or so bytes of an example in hex in your question?

Comment: I don't understand what u mean HEX code ?

Comment: The bytes you're feeding to the gzip decoder, represented in hexadecimal. Something like: `1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 cb 48 cd c9 c9 d7 51 c8 00 51 8a 0c 00 9d 3f 6c b5 0e 00 00 00`.

Comment: I don't use Gzip anywhere of my code. With .net framework 3.5 there is no error but .net framework 4.0 and above i get gzip error but i don't use gzip. I think webservice sends data with gzip format then framework automaticly try to use gzip. But I can't solve the problem. The wsdl adress is here: [Link](http://lisansws.epdk.org.tr/services/bildirimPetrolAkaryakitFiyatlari?wsdl)